# How to set javascript variable value from selected textboxes to another textbox

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using `onclick` javascript alert to show my selected value from textbox. Now I want to set these value to another textbox. I am new to **javascript** help me if u can. 
I want these two values into two textboxes but don't how it is possible.Here is my code.

```
onClick="javascript:alert('Date select from '+this.form.date3.value+' to '+this.form.date4.value);"
```

Comment: Post your code to get helped fast..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value like this..

```
document.getElementid('Textbox1').value=this.form.date3.value;
document.getElementid('Textbox2').value=this.form.date4.value;
```

Comment: Alert show me two selected values but not filled in textboxes where I want.

Comment: You have to pick the id of textbox from browser by inspect element  and use it in the document.getElementid('Textbox1').value code...